# Retrieve information from a seperate sheet, based on a dynamically changed key

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I want a list of products and their prices like so:

```
         D       E
      ---------------
  1   product | price
      ---------------
  2    hat    | 2.00
      ---------------
```

I'd like this list (and other like it) to be in their own tabs. I want my main tab to be able to pull the product name from a drop down list in one cell but auto-populate the price in another cell like this:

```
1 | hat | 2.00 (this is automatically populated when I choose hat)
```

I would also like more properties of the hat populated besides just price. I realize this is probably more for something like Access but I'd really like to do it in Excel.

Comment: `VLOOKUP` or `INDEX(MATCH())` will populate the fields given the drop down input

Comment: Can you elaborate more? what's the population you want to split in sheets? what will in each sheet by excel?

Comment: @GuyLouZon - In sheet 1 I have a list of people's names. Next to their name, I have a drop down which says what they are getting (hat, shirt, pants). The cell to the right of that will autofill the price of that product. Sheet 2 will just hold the products, prices, and descriptions, etc.

Comment: sheet 2 will hold the product details of what? all products? sheet per person?

Comment: @GuyLouZon - Sheet 2 will hold all products. Not per-person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, then there are 2 sheets:
1. people sheet, with a product of choice
2. products tables

I would suggest the following:
Add a column in the people sheet and use data validation:
*Data ribbon - > data validation*
On the popup that opens choose *list*, and in the list range, select the product names from the products sheet. This will create a drop-down, for the products, in the people sheet
Say the column is `column D`

Then in the next column, I would add a vlookups, that would search the product's attributes:
In E2, for example, assuming that the products sheet is named `products`, column A is the name, and column B is the 1st attribute to be pulled:

```
=VLOOKUP($D2,products!$A$2:$I$2000,2,0)
```

The following VLOOKUP should return the next attribute, say from column F

```
=VLOOKUP($D2,products!$A$2:$I$2000,6,0)
```

If you'd like to better manage the attributes displayed in the people sheet, then instead of constant column lookup indexes: 2,6 in the example, you can use cells that will contain the column index and change in dynamically, in a `keys` sheet, for example